# DbContext as DI when migrating from Core 2 to Core 2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0, ef-core-2.0, asp.net-core-2.1, ef-core-2.1

I was working on .Net Core 2 and everything was working fine, but after i created .Net Core 2.1 angular based application i get runtime error : `Cannot consume scoped service 'RealEstate.Data.RealEstatesContext' from singleton 'RealEstate.Repositories.DI.IAdRepository'.` I understand that error was occured because of scope differences. But how than I use DI with Dbcontext.

Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
        services.AddDbContext<RealEstatesContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("RealEstatesContext"))
        ); 
        services.AddScoped<GetAdHandler>();
        services.AddSingleton<IAdRepository, AdRepository>();
}
```

GetAdHandler.cs

```
public class GetAdHandler
{
    private readonly IAdRepository _adRepository;

    public GetAdHandler(IAdRepository adRepository) 
    {
        _adRepository = adRepository;
    }

    protected override async Task<BaseResponse<AdDto>> HandleAsync(GetRequest<int> request) 
    {
        AdDto ad = await _adRepository.GetAdAsync(request.Id);
        return new BaseResponse<AdDto> {
            Result = ad
        };
    }
}
```

AdRepository.cs

```
public class AdRepository : IAdRepository 
{
    private readonly RealEstatesContext _context;

    public AdRepository(RealEstatesContext context) 
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public async Task<List<AdCardDto>> GetAdsAsync() 
    {
        _context.Ads.ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The version 2.1 of .Net Core just reveals to you a bug you're holding before migrating. Your class `AdRepository` is injected as a singleton instance because of this:

```
services.AddSingleton<IAdRepository, AdRepository>();
```

But that same class has a dependence to your context class `RealEstatesContext` which is injected and scoped by default which means that each HTTP request will have its own instance of the `RealEstatesContext` class.

So imagine many users using your application. Each users requests will be assigned to a specific HTTP request that is different to other. So here in your application each HTTP request will share the same `AdRepository` (single instance for all requests) but other users may deal with a `RealEstatesContext` instance that may be instanciated by another user's HTTP request. This kind of bug can be seen only many users are using your application at the same times.

So to solve it just make sure you inject your `AdRepository` as scoped like below:

```
services.AddScoped<IAdRepository, AdRepository>();
```

Instead of

```
services.AddSingleton<IAdRepository, AdRepository>();
```